# Deriving from virtual class

Tags: c++

In project I have one virtual class:

```
class Base {
public:
    Base();
    virtual void insert(const Node& n);
    virtual Node extract_min() = 0;
    virtual int size() = 0;
    virtual ~Base() {};
};
```

And I have derived class:

```
class Derived: public Base {
public:
    derived(int MaxN = MAXN);

    void insert(const Node& n);
    Node extract_min();
    int size() {
        return cnt;
    }

    virtual ~Derived();
};
```

And its constructor:

```
Derived::Derived(int MaxN): Base() {
    //something happes here;
}
```

And its destructor:

```
Derived::~Derived() {
    free(my_array);
}
```

But when I make it I keep getting this error on linking stage:

```
obj/Derived.o: In function `Derived::~Derived()':
Derived.cpp:(.text+0x160): undefined reference to `vtable for Base'
obj/Derived.o: In function `Derived::Derived(int)':
Derived.cpp:(.text+0x199): undefined reference to `Base::Base()'
Derived.cpp:(.text+0x516): undefined reference to `vtable for Base'
```

does anybody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
undefined reference to `vtable for Base'
```

This error means that you forgot to provide definitions for (impure) virtual functions in Base class. From other errors it seems you missed definition for all members.

Comment: Yes, I'm stupid. I forgot to define constructor in base class After I added `Base() {};` everything works fine. Thanks for your help and time, sir.

Comment: @Dima You can also remove the default constructor and let the compiler make one for you. Less code to think about and maintain.

Answer (score -1):

You should add the definition of your ctor for the base class.
This could resolve the link errors.

```
class Base {
public:
    Base{};
    virtual void insert(const Node& n);
    virtual Node extract_min() = 0;
    virtual int size() = 0;
    virtual ~Base() {};
};
```

Also you had add the definition of the virtual functions inherited in your derived class